# How to extract specific icon from ico file with java?

Tags: java, icons

I want to create a java application that can extract specific sized icon from an ico file.

I.e. extract a 64 x 64 icon from a multi-icon Ico file.

Is there any way of doing this in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't support .ico files by default. It supports .png, .gif, and .jpg. For reading the .ico files, you may need to find an ImageIO extension.